# Django delete all cookies for all users

Tags: django, cookies, django-1.4

I have the django view to set the value in cookies **'no_show_dialog'** when a user clicks **'Don't remind me anymore'** in the modal dialog.

Now i changed that dialog completely and want to reset that cookie for all users, so they will have to see it again at least once.

I know there is a way to delete the cookie in a view for a particular user:

```
response.delete_cookie('no_show_dialog')
```

**But how to loop over all users and remove that cookie once?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. Cookies are stored on the client; the only time you have access to them is when the particular browser makes a request and receives the response.

The best thing to do here is to simply use a different name for the cookie from now on. This will ensure that no users will have it set initially. Alternatively you might consider using the session for future settings.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said you cannot delete all cookies in response as they are stored on client side.

In Django you create a response object for a particular request object in your views. Which means that you can only delete a cookie for that particular request and not for all the requests that was served by your Django server.

What you can do here is set expiry time for a cookie by using max_age as keyword argument in set_cookie method For Example :

```
response = HttpResponse('your response')
response.set_cookie('user_id', user_id, max_age=30)
return response
```

This will expire the cookie after the specified time for every client.

Comment: Ok, i see. I know that, i think the best way to do it is to rename the cookie i use, so it will reset all the functionality.